# Frequent, small window.scrollBy() calls causing jittery scroll on mobile

Tags: javascript, html, mobile

### The issue

I noticed an issue where repeatedly using `window.scrollBy(...)` with small values causes the scroll to jitter a lot on mobile. I say mobile, but I've only been able to test it on my own phone (iPhone 13 Max Pro), so it might be device specific, or just iOS specific. I suspect that it could have something to do with the adaptive refresh rate on ProMotion displays, but I'm really not sure. I did not experience any jitter on my Macbook Pro, even in Safari (for reference, my MBP does not have a ProMotion display).

Here's a quick video showcasing the issue: https://imgur.com/a/DBf6MaD

### Reproduction code

I've created some bare bones code that reproduces the issue.

```html
    <html>
      <body>
        <div id="app" />
        <script>
          function createDivs() {
            const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
            for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
              const div = document.createElement("div");
              div.textContent = "Test";
              div.style.fontSize = "44px";
              appDiv.appendChild(div);
            }
          }

          function App() {
            createDivs();
            setInterval(() => {
              window.scrollBy(0, 5);
            }, 10);
          }

          App();
        </script>
      </body>
    </html>
```

To reproduce create an folder with an index.html file containing the above code and then host the folder locally using something like [http-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server). Access the server via your phone.

This is probably not easily reproducible in code sandbox type environments for reasons I'll cover below.

### Diving deeper, and a solution

I've noticed that this doesn't seem to be reproducible in code sandbox type environments, or anything else that runs the code in an iframe (storybook for example). This is what got me thinking that the issue might have something to do with using the top scroll context vs. a nested scroll context. An iframe has a separate scroll context from the page that it's running in, and the scroll behavior seems to work fine in an iframe.

Based on this knowledge/hint I tried a number of different things and found that nested scroll contexts do indeed seem to fix the issue, but I wanted to scroll the entire page. So the next thing I tried was making `body` responsible for scrolling instead of `html`. This actually solves the problem. Here's some example code and a video illustrating this:

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      html {
        overflow-y: hidden;
      }
      body {
        overflow-y: auto;
        height: 100dvh;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="app" />
    <script>
      function createDivs() {
        const appDiv = document.getElementById("app");
        for (let i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
          const div = document.createElement("div");
          div.textContent = "Test";
          div.style.fontSize = "44px";
          appDiv.appendChild(div);
        }
      }

      function App() {
        createDivs();
        setInterval(() => {
          document.body.scrollBy(0, 5);
        }, 10);
      }

      App();
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Video: https://imgur.com/a/y0kZeIg

The only changes in this code compared to the 'Reproduction code' are the styles I added to `html` and `body` to get the body to take over the scrolling, and the `window.scrollBy(...)` changing to `document.body.scrollBy(...)` since now it's the body that we need to scroll.

### Questions

Finally, my question is... why? Does anybody know why the above solution works, and if there is a better solution? I don't really want to make the body responsible for the scroll if I can avoid it, because if other developers on the team try to do things like `window.scrollBy(...)` it just won't work and they'll have to spend time figuring out why. This could be a non-issue with some lint rules to guide them, but if there is an easier solution I'd love to hear it!